# htaccess URL redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect an url(A) to another url(B). When url(B) loading, I need to run some code and it might redirect to another url(C).

Example :- Like paypal notification url, I need to run some code in the background when a user browses specific type urls.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect A to B with a `Redirect 301 A B`, and in B's script don't send headers until you have to redirect (or don't). If you have to redirect, send a `header("Location: " + $c)` and then `exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Location` HTTP header along with one of the various 30X HTTP result codes can be used to redirect the client.